# Capture screen shot of a Google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to capture a screen shot on the browser, I have already used Html2canvas and Google static map API but in Html2canvas, it did not render the map data and I got a blank white page. In the other case i.e. while using Google static map API, my url is getting too big as my object is too big.

As I want to capture a screen shot of the map with polylines and markers, please tell me any alternative which helps me to capture a screen shot of the Google map with polylines and marker. Please keep in mind I am plotting many markers and polylines on the map.

Comment: you should share code snippet so we can help

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to take a look at the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check what sort of questions you can [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is very unclear, and appears to be asking for a recommendation, which is off-topic. It also has formatting problems.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html
As the website says "Since PhantomJS is using WebKit, a real layout and rendering engine, it can capture a web page as a screenshot."

An example to make a screenshot of github.com (also from the PhantomJS site)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```